# Jquery fadeIn() affects first child only in Chrome

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

Hello I have following html:

```
...
<span class="article">
  <div class="placeholder">
    <img src="image.jpg">
  </div>
  <h3>...</h3>
  <h4>...</h4>
  <p>...</p>
</span>
...
```

And js:

```
...
$('.article').each(function(index, element) {

  var article = $(this);

  article.fadeIn(1500);
  ...
}
```

It works fine on firefox, but on chrome only the placeholder div fades in instead of all span.

Anyone had this problem?

Comment: Is your `<span>` element styled as `display: block`? Otherwise, putting block elements (`<div>`) inside inline elements (`<span>`) is not supported.

Comment: Thanks @frédéric-hamidi. That was the problem.